# Should we accept Immigration refuges?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, immigration-questions, expat-questions

I know, I know, expat questions are off topic here. But with the closing of Immigration, they currently have nowhere to go! There's a proposal to give them a permanent home in [Expatriates](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates?referrer=QUmSv5GdKmx9c2qQO4fLxA2), but until that is running they'll simply be deported to whatever site will take them, or worse.

Should we allow them to stay here until they have somewhere to go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think broadening the scope to include expat and immigration questions would too much muddy our currently pretty well-defined area of expertise. I don't think the two communities are really the same so I don't think it would be harmonious.

I think it would be much better to start at grass roots with a proposal on Area 51 and promote it as hard as you can to get followers and then people committing. You have to generate enough interest and then maintain that interest so Stack Exchange believes you are not going away. Then you'll get a private beta to prove yourselves.

That's what we did. It took some work and effort and it was shaky in the beginning. I think that's what expat and immigration people need to do to. Build a community and you'll get your site too. And we'll help by mentioning and promoting your proposal often, and your site too when you get it.

Comment: Yeah we took a while to get moving, and it's been many hours and hours of answering, editing and searching.  And some serious trials.  But now we have a site with week-on-week growth, nearly out of public beta after nearly 15 months.  Yay!  I'd be happy to support an expat/immigration site (and supported both proposals on area51).  But without other support, they may just be a pipedream.

Comment: I'm actually not a big fan of the expats proposal: I think most questions expatiates face tend to be either regional (in which case they'd be more appropriate in a country-specific site) or beneficial to most travelers (in which case they belong on travel). My main complaint is that questions are being migrated or closed when I feel they would add to the community. But I can make that case elsewhere.

Comment: @Shep: Have you tried asking some of your questions as example questions on the Area 51 proposal? You can also discuss the scope of the proposal etc there.

Answer (score 6):

**No**.  Expat and Immigration questions are off topic here. It's in our [faq]. [It's been stated as such by the SE overlords](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/expat-questions) - (note Dori was SE staff at the time). And we've had this discussion both on your question AND on your other meta question.

All we can do is promote the Expat proposal and hope that it gets acceptance, so that we won't have to keep having this debate.

The [original travel proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel) was for 'road warriors and seasoned travellers'.  No expat or immigration about it.  It's been diluted a bit to have almost any travel question, but let's keep it accurate about travel, and not add other domains in just because there's a little bit of overlap.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the extent to which this is a decision of "the SE overlords": my impression was that this was a choice made by the moderators on Travel.

Comment: -1 for drawing my other questions into it, in my opinion those things aren't related to my post. (if you're going to mention them, at least provide links) But other than that I'd consider this post helpfu.

Comment: @Shep - the [one where it was discussed](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147/expat-questions) - the accepted answer was by Dori.  She is (was) SE staff (overlords).  And therefore their word stands.  As a result, it was put into our FAQ.  And given we've pointed out expat/immigration are related and off-topic on both your other questions, that makes these things very relevant.

Comment: My understanding is that the moderators are responsible for keeping the sites in the shape Stack Exchange wants them.